# Why does my matrix say character,13 and character,14?

Tags: r

I have imported data from a txt file that is separated by commas using readLines() and strsplit('',split=','). This gave me 15 lines to work with. I need to split the data into 4 columns and 49 rows, however when I try to it says that 49 is not a multiple of 15 and yields me with a matrix that changes everything within my previous list with 'character,13', 'character,14', and a bunch of other entries like it. The file contains data that isn't properly split up within the lines so my plan was to convert it to a matrix and then a data frame as per my homework assignment. Code and output are below, any pointers in the right direction is helpful :)

```
stat <- readLines('filepath')
stat <- strsplit(stat,split=',')
stat <- matrix(stat[1:15],ncol=4,byrow=T)
```

This code yields the following matrix below.

[image: Output from R]

Prior to turning it into a matrix it contained data read from 15 lines of a text file, the observations aren't consistent and span different lines.

Comment: You have lists in your cells, try `strsplit(stat,split=',')[[1]]`, since `strsplit` throws lists, and you probably have just one element in it.

Comment: I've got 15 elements in it, I've done it in SAS as well so I know I need 49 lines that span across 4 variables however R doesn't like it when I go to split it into 4 columns and 49 rows.

Comment: Why are you not using read.table?

Comment: The data for each variable isn't neat on each line, some observations are on other lines, isn't that one of the requirements for read.table?

Comment: I wonder how your attempt is supposed to deal with that issue. Your use of `matrix` seems pretty premature.